# Where does Asset Studio store the Google Play Store icon?

Tags: android, android-studio, icons

I run Android Studio 3.2.1 with all updates. I generate all icons from an SVG master artwork, so resolution is not an issue.

All icons get generated and stored into \res\mipmap as the previews have shown inside Asset Studio. I can also see my Google Play Store icon, rather huge next to all the other sizes in the preview.

But after the actual generation, I cannot find the Play Store Icon. The online documentation here
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio?utm_source=android-studio
does not mention the location of the extra icons.

Bonus question: If generated this way inside the Android Studio, will the package include the Store Icon, or do I need to upload it manually in the Store Console like before?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The play store icon *ic_launcher-web.png* is stored in the **main** folder of the module. In Android Studio, you can see it underneath the file *AndroidManifest.xml*.

[image: file tree with ic_launcher-web.png]

Comment: Awesome, it was hidden. After your answer I went much higher in my files structure and then down again into app and then src and then main and now it is showing. Needed some refresh or whatever. This is helpful, I will give you the tick of course. How can I tick you extra for speed and screenshot? Thank you!!!

Comment: @Martin Zaske - yes, Android Studio is sometimes slow to refresh a file tree. But hey, all in all it works fine ;)

Comment: So today I learnt about the refresh and about patience. Indeed, without that Studio I could not even dream to make a custom keyboard or other little stuff. Thanks again.

Comment: Cheers this is awesome. Had no idea it was here

Comment: If you do generate now an image asset you won't get the "-web" suffix but the "-playstore" suffix.

Answer (score 0):

I had to exit from Android Studio and go through the Windows directory system in order to see the Play Store image :)

Answer (score 0):

just to ease the steps told by "Bö macht Blau"

```
right click -> AndroidManifest.xml -> open in -> explorer
```

[image]
[image]